# Jssor Slider CSS separation?

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

I'm working with the Jssor slider. I have an issue when attempting to separate the slider styles into an external CSS document. For example:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1140px;     height: 437px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Doing something like this below doesn't work.

```
#slider1_container {
position: relative; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
width: 1140px; 
height: 437px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
```

I've double checked and everything is linked correctly. Any suggestions or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If the slider code is automatically adding inline style, you won't be able to override this with ordinary cascaded CSS rules -- unless you use `!important` on each item -- because inline styles have a higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version, you can move all inline styles to css file/block by specifying class name to each element.

Comment: It isn't clear from your answer as to why using a class name would make any difference (to that of targeting via id), does jssor detect that a class name exists on the container, and so avoids setting inline style?

Comment: id (except the main container `slider1_container`) is also reasonable. To initialize jssor slider, the main container (`slider1_container`) would be duplicated, and the id would be removed for the second one.